# Static native method: cannot resolve corresponding JNI function

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Im getting the mentioned error while declaring static native method:
[image]

From the native side the link is working as expected:
[image]

Everything works as expected the problem is just the link(Android Studio 3.1.1) from java to the native reference which is broken for static(works for non-static ones) methods.

Comment: Must be **public** i.e. `public static native void jniInitCore();` on the `Java` side.

Comment: No, it's not. I have private non-static methods linked properly. I don't think its code related as everything works ok. I think its on a project/android studio level setup.

Comment: I did not see this before a recent upgrade. I opened a [ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78095963) for this bug.

Comment: They [promise](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78095963#comment2) to have this fixed in the next canary build of 3.2.

Answer (score 3):

There exists a funny workaround:

1. remove the word 'static' in Java.
2. click on the red bulb to 'Create function Java_…_jniInitCore()'
3. restore the word 'static' in Java file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the type of the second argument in JNI method from `jclass` to `jobject`. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert but I changed the second parameter from `jobject` to `jclass` and it worked for me.